# What does the term 'modified residue position' in phosphorylation mean?

Tags: proteins, terminology, amino-acids, phosphorylation

Does it mean the position of the amino acid in the protein sequence, or something else?

For example, I came across the phrase "S 368 phosphoryation" where S is the modified residue and 368 is the modified residue position. What does it all mean?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, the `368` stands for the position of the amino acid in the protein's sequence - this particular serine is the 368th residue in the protein counting from the amino-terminal end.